# How to opt out of running a doc test?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing a Rust library and I want to provide examples in my documentation that

1. compile as part of running `cargo test`
2. do *not* run.

Is this possible?

I'm writing a database client library, and the examples make use of a hypothetical, non-existing database server. As such, the examples always fail when run, but it's important that the examples be valid syntactically. Hence my requirements above.

If there's no way to do what I want, then how does one opt out of having `cargo test` run a specific doc test? I.e., have `cargo run` compile-and-run some doc tests but completely ignore some others?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is documented in [*The rustdoc book*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/), specifically the [chapter about attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#attributes).

Your opening codeblock delimiter should look like:

````
/// ```no_run
````

From the book:

> ````
> /// ```no_run
> /// loop {
> ///     println!("Hello, world");
> /// }
> /// ```
> ````
>
> The `no_run` attribute will compile your code, but not run it. This is
>   important for examples such as "Here's how to retrieve a web page,"
>   which you would want to ensure compiles, but might be run in a test
>   environment that has no network access.

To omit build completely use `ignore` instead of `no_run`.

Comment: I think in later versions of Rust `no_run` no longer works, but the book doesn't seem to be clear about what replaced it.

Comment: Coming from 2022, and `no_run` worked just fine for me on the latest stable rust + cargo as of this comment posting date (I got the `passed` message for the test when running them)

Answer (score 55):

Put this in Cargo.toml:

```
[lib]
doctest = false
```

Found it here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html

Answer (score 1):

You can address problems using `should_panic`, almost identically to using `no_run`. `no_run` is considered successful irrespective of the result, whereas `should_panic` must induce a panic. A crucial point to remember is that both necessitate successful compilation.

In this case, `no_run` seems more fitting, but I leave this answer for other readers.