# How to turn off cargo doc test and compile for a specific module in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

I have some generated `.rs` code (from grpc proto files) and they are checked in with my normal Rust code under src but in some sub modules. The issue is that when doing `cargo test` the doc test will run and some of the generated `.rs` have comments with indentations (code blocks) and cargo doc test will try to compile them and fail.

For example `cargo test` will try to compile (and perhaps run these lines) [show here](https://github.com/liufuyang/bigtable_rs/blob/main/bigtable_rs/src/google/google.bigtable.v2.rs#L267-L283).

Is there a way to exclude or ignore those generated `.rs` for doc test (without manually changing them)?

Comment: I see you've already updated your linked example with text-fences and from what I can tell ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32429369), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50312190), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38292741)), there doesn't seem to be a way without modifying the documentation. I would've figured you could work around it by conditional `#[doc(hidden)]` but `cargo test` seems to run them regardless.

Comment: Probably for the best though, without the text-fences, it might render improperly when browsing the `cargo doc`s.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated answer:

I have hacked together a crate [tonic-disable-doctest](https://crates.io/crates/tonic-disable-doctest) for disabling doctests, it may be used as such:

```rust
use tonic_disable_doctest::BuilderEx;

fn main() {
    tonic_build::configure()
        .disable_doctests_for_types([".google.api.HttpRule"])
        .compile(
            &["proto/api/google/api/http.proto"],
            &["proto/"],
        )
        .unwrap();
}
```

---

#### Old answer

###### My solution

I've resolved this by injecting code that separates the offending comment and the structure underneath:

```
fn main() {
    tonic_build::configure()
        .type_attribute(
            ".google.api.HttpRule",
            "#[cfg(not(doctest))]\n\
             #[allow(dead_code)]\n\
             pub struct HttpRuleComment{}\n\
             /// HACK: see docs in [`HttpRuleComment`] ignored in doctest pass",
        )
        .compile(
            &["proto/api/google/api/http.proto"],
            &["proto/"],
        )
        .unwrap();
}
```

###### Explanation:

1. `tonic_build` allows adding attributes to specific protobuf paths, but it does not discern between attributes or any other strings.
2. `#[cfg(not(doctest))]` excludes the comment's offending code from doc tests, because it excludes the structure it's added to, this trick is taken from [discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/disabling-rustdoc-tests-for-module/50110/5) on Rust user forum.
3. `#[allow(dead_code)]` silences warnings about injected structure not being used (as it shouldn't be used).
4. `pub struct HttpRuleComment{}` creates a public structure that can be referenced in the docstring for the original struct.
5. `/// ...[HttpRuleComment]...` is a docstring referencing injected struct, so that the original documentation can still be accessed.

###### Notes:

I'm not sure if your case is the same, but I found myself on this SO page a lot while searching for an answer and decided to share the results.

In my case, the only offending comment was in `HttpRule`, you may need to write a macro or do lots of copy-paste if you happen to have multiple offending comments.

Comment: Aha, thank you, I am also using tonic_build, and the issue was also related to some google API protos (some bigtable proto to be more specific). So perhaps this can work for my case.

Comment: @FuyangLiu you may mark this as the answer if it worked or provide some more input as to what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I need to find time to test it, but I feel your solution is not very generic and needs some tweaks for each scenario?

Comment: I thought that it makes more sense to publish it as a crate =) edited the answer